# Why OnFinished Eventhandler is invoking continuously?

Tags: animation, javafx, javafx-8

I am new to JavaFX and have a problem with this code

```
  pongAnimation = new Timeline(
    new KeyFrame(new Duration(1.0), t -> {
         checkForCollision();
      })
  );
  pongAnimation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
```

Why does the Eventhandler

```
 t -> { checkForCollision(); }
```

start after the Animantion has ended?

We don't have the code

```
   pongAnimation.setOnFinished( t -> {
         checkForCollision();)
```

In my Workbook, it says

> When a KeyFrame has an action event handler, the code in that
>   handler—which in this case is once again a lambda expression—is
>   executed when the time for that KeyFrame is reached.

My question is when the KeyFrame has an action event handler, why does it start the event again?

Comment: Which animation are you talking about? Can you add a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which replicates your problem?

Comment: With this code, the `checkForCollision()` method will be invoked every millisecond.

Comment: Actually, `checkForCollision()` will be invoked once a pulse because timelines are keyed off the animation subsystem of JavaFX which does not fire any more often than once a pulse.  Usually a pulse will occur sixty times a second.

Comment: My question is, whyy will the checkForCollision()  invoked every millisecond.  We dont have something like xyz.setonfinished(..);

Comment: @jewelsea Yes, good point.

Comment: @alexsuhaiö I don't really understand your question. The quote you gives explains exactly what happens. You have a `KeyFrame` that has a duration of 1 millisecond: this means it represents the point on the timeline 1 millisecond after the start of the timeline. So when that time - 1 millisecond - is reached, the code in the handler is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does the Eventhandler start after the Animantion has ended?

Because you set the animation to repeat indefinitely by

```
pongAnimation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
```

If you want it to play only once do

```
pongAnimation.setCycleCount(1);
```